# Improving performance of LEFT JOIN / GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `snippets` and `platforms`. Each snippet belongs to a platform (fork_id is nullable and links to another record on the same table). Structure:

```
PLATFORMS (id, name, slug, syntax)
SNIPPETS (id, platform_id, fork_id, private etc.)
```

I'm now trying to run a query to get the total number of snippets for each platform. The query is slow (between 10 - 20 seconds) when the snippets table has a million records.

```
SELECT platforms.id, name, slug, syntax, COUNT(*) AS total FROM platforms 
LEFT JOIN snippets on platforms.id = snippets.platform_id
WHERE fork_id IS NULL
AND private = 0
GROUP BY platforms.id, name
ORDER BY total DESC, name asc;
```

Some additional information:

- snippets.id and platform.id have primary key indexes.
- fork_id and platform_id have foreign key indexes.
- private and platforms.name have indexes.

Running an `EXPLAIN` query offers the following:

[image: Explain query]

How can I get the performance to an acceptable level?
Thanks!

Comment: It's amazingly weird to group by the thing you're counting

Comment: @Strawberry - how would you change the query to produce the count for each platform then?

Comment: @John1984 - Can you add sample data and expected result. `Group by` in `Mysql` is super confusing

Comment: No need, see answer below...

Comment: @John1984 - Brilliant response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, this type of query can be faster with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.slug, p.syntax,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM snippets s
        WHERE p.id = s.platform_id AND
              s.fork_id IS NULL AND
              s.private = 0
       ) AS total
FROM platforms  p
ORDER BY total DESC, name asc;
```

Then, you want an index on `snippets(platform_id, fork_id, private)`.

I should note that your original query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.slug, p.syntax, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM platforms p JOIN
     snippets s
     on p.id = s.platform_id
WHERE s.fork_id IS NULL AND s.private = 0
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
ORDER BY total DESC, name asc;
```

Because the `WHERE` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  For this query, you can try an index on `snippets(private, fork_id, platform_id)`.

Comment: Your first query got me the results in 200ms, which is perfect. I also tried the second, but it took longer at 1.3s. Needless to say, 200ms is more than acceptable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two things going on here I can see.  One is the counting, and the other is the display of the details from the `platforms` table.

Let's count first.

```
                     SELECT platform_id, COUNT(*) snips
                       FROM snippets
                      WHERE fork_id IS NULL
                        AND private = 0
                      GROUP BY platform_id
```

To make this as fast as possible, create a compound index on the (`private, fork_id, platform_id)` columns of the `snippets` table. That way the inner query can do a so-called index scan, about which you can read.

Let's report the details now that we have the counts.

```
       SELECT a.id, a.name, a.slug, a.syntax, b.snips
         FROM platforms a
    LEFT JOIN (
                     SELECT platform_id, COUNT(*) snips
                       FROM snippets
                      WHERE fork_id IS NULL
                        AND private = 0
                      GROUP BY platform_id
              ) b ON a.platform_id = b.platform_id
       ORDER BY b.snips DESC, a.name ASC;
```

The trick is: simplify simplify simplify when aggregating (grouping) large tables.

Comment: Thanks for your response O. Jones. The query does indeed work. It ran in 400ms (slightly slower than Gordon's first query), but always useful to have more examples to study!

Comment: @john1984 given that this is an outer join as opposed to an inner join, you're not really comparing like with like. Switch this to an inner join and, appropriately indexed, I'll wager that this performs faster.

Comment: @Strawberry:  agreed. But it seems to me from the original questioner's code that he doesn't want the items from his leftmost table suppressed if they don't match items in the rightmost table.